# Problema de lógica en Dropdown en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito crear un menú desplegable llamado Servicios, de momento conseguí que al hacerle click a una de las opciones de dicho menú me redireccione a una pagina especifica para ese servicio. Mi duda es como puedo hacer para que, si decidiera solo hacer click en servicios, me lleve a una pagina genérica donde estarán las mismas opciones que en el menú desplegable?

```
`import { Link} from "react-router-dom"
import './header.scss'
import {MdOutlineKeyboardArrowDown, MdOutlineKeyboardArrowUp} from 'react-icons/md'
import { useState } from "react"

const services = [  
  'Content creator',
  'Product manager',
  'Fotografa',
  'Film maker'
]

const Header = () => { 
  

  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false) 
  

  return (
    <header className="header-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>                
                
                <li 
                    className="navbar-list"                                    
                    onMouseEnter={() => setMenu(true)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => setMenu(false)}>
                    Servicios 
                    {menu ? 
                      <MdOutlineKeyboardArrowUp 
                      className="arrow" 
                    /> : 
                      <MdOutlineKeyboardArrowDown 
                      className="arrow" />}
                    {
                      menu && (
                        <ul className="services-list">
                          {
                            services.map(li => (
                              
                              <Link to={`/services/${li}`}>
                                <li>{li}</li>
                              </Link>
                              
                            ))
                          }
                          
                        </ul>
                      )
                    }
                  </li>
                
                
                <Link to='/'><li className="logo">Aixa Franzoni</li></Link>
                <Link to='/contact'><li className="navbar-list">Contacto</li></Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
export default Header`
```

De momento este es lo que tengo, intente agregar un Link que envuelva todo ese li y que me redireccione a la pagina de servicios y pareciera funcionar, pero al hacerlo me tira por consola que no puedo tener un Link anidado dentro de otro Link, como podría resolver esto ?

Comment: En vez de añadir un elemento link a ese li, puedes añadirle un evento onClick, y en dicho evento redirigirlo a la pagina deseada con `history.push("/services")` o `navigate("/services")` dependiendo de la version que uses de react-router

Comment: Eso lo había pensado antes, lo intenté y no me funciono. Cree una función: `const handleClick = (li) => { navigate(`/services/${li}`) }` pero no me redirecciona a esa pagina.